# parsing XML files with tags that has the charachter "&" in the value

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0

I parsing XML with a powershell script, the script fails where it gets to parse a file 
with "&"

```
[xml]$XMLfile = Get-Content -Path $filePath 
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "An error occurred while parsing
```

file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<property>this is the value of the script & there is another value </property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` character indicates the start of a character reference. Following one with a space makes the XML is invalid. Fix the XML. To represent a `&` character as data, use `&amp;`.